# Opening a file with a PHAsset URI from a Webview

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-camera, react-native-webview, camera-roll

From the camera roll, I get a list of URIs in the ph://xxxxx format.

If I use these URIs in Image or ImageBackground components everything works as expected.

I want to show these photos in a webview. Adding to the html an img tag with that kind of URI doesn't work.

Am I missing something?
Is there any workaround to display such images in a webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, after trying various solutions, it doesn't seem to work at the time of writing.
I solved getting the absolute path of the image, which in my case meant copying the file from the cameraroll to the app document directory.